# Laravel overriding EloquentUserProvider to change password field name in validateCredentials()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've managed to change the password field in the code through overriding various classes/methods. But I after trying to override EloquentUserProvider and it's validateCredentials() method I keep getting an error -

```
ErrorException in AuthUserProvider.php line 15:
Argument 1 passed to App\Providers\AuthUserProvider::__construct() must be an instance of App\Helpers\Sha1Hasher, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given
```

I created an override App\Providers\AuthUserProvider.php -

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;
use App\Helpers\Sha1Hasher as HasherContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;

class AuthUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{
/**
 * AuthUserProvider constructor.
 * @param HasherContract $hasher
 * @param string $model
 */
public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher, $model)
{
    parent::__construct($hasher, $model);
}

/**
 * Validate a user against the given credentials.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
 * @param  array  $credentials
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    // $plain = $credentials['sha_pass_hash'];
    // return HasherContract::check(...);;
}
}
```

using Laravel 5.2.22.

Comment: Please you be more specific about what you wanna achieve here. Did you change password column name in users table ?

Comment: yes i've changed the password column name to sha1_pass and have a custom Hasher. What I'm trying to do is override the validateCredentials() method in the EloquentUserProvider class since it has the password column name hardcoded as $credentials['password']; and also apply a check with the Sha1 Hasher.

Comment: Password column is not hardcoded in Laravel auth system. You can tell the Auth system to use a specified column as password column

Comment: I've done that within the Users.php model where you can override getAuthPassword method of the Authenticatable class and change $this->password variable to the name of your column. Now unless i'm missing something, there is a final call to validateCredentials() in EloquentUserProvider/DatabaseUserProvider class before logging you in where it has the 'password' field hardcoded and verifies the hashed password with the plain text.

Comment: All I am saying why go through this stress when you can do this:  `if(Auth::attempt(['new_password_column' => $password, 'new_username_column'=>$username])) {  //login success }`

Comment: there's a call to validateCredentials() in Auth::attempt() though

Comment: if you simply want to log user in using particular table column names just try this `if(Auth::attempt(['new_password_column' => $password, 'new_username_column'=>$username])) { //login success }` no need for what you have done so far

Comment: But if you don't pass 'password' as an index of the array you send to Auth:attempt(), it will throw an undefined index error as there is a hardcoded line in the code of the method validateCredentials() where it requires the 'password' index.

Comment: have you tried ? Its not hard coded

Comment: yep i've tried and the full code is -
    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }

Comment: Try this: if(Auth::attempt(['new_password_column' => $password, 'new_username_column'=>$username])) { //login success }`

Comment: `if(Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt([
            $this->loginUsername() => $credentials[$this->loginUsername()],
            $this->getAuthPassword() => $credentials[$this->getAuthPassword()]],
            $request->has('remember')
        )) { // login success } `
is what i'm using, where loginUsername returns 'username' and the getAuthPassword() returns 'sha1_pass'. the $credentials array indexes i've manually set before i use it here.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I am saying. You are not trying what I asked you to try. You are doing it your way

Comment: Tried it your way, still get the same error. Maybe we're not using the same Laravel version.

Comment: Hey, were you able to figured it out? I'm having similar issue with validateCredentials function. It uses hash check by default. Yet I don't want to match using hashed password since I'm using on my non-hashed passwords in DB. So I was looking for how to override validateCredentials function. If you have any insight can you help?

Comment: Hey, nope, the only way I got through that was the edit the file manually or create a custom service provider, hasher and model.

Comment: does this help? https://gist.github.com/veelasky/9830696

Answer (score 2):

How did you 'override' the instance of `EloquentUserProvider` ? Because Laravel is creating the `Auth` instance based on what `auth.driver` you have set.

Check `Illuminate/Auth/CreatesUserProviders@createUserProvider` it is hardcoded, based on driver, to load `EloquentUserProvider`. What you can try is `bind` your instance to the `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider`.

The error you get, means that your `__construct` isn't getting the proper input. Based on how your code looks like, its basicly doing this:

```
new AuthUserProvider($app);
```

But what it should do:

```
return new EloquentUserProvider($this->app['hash'], $config['model']);
```

If it is not working try registering a custom provider through the `AuthManager` class. See `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager@provider` line +- 266.

Maybe!! not tested:

```
auth()->provider(AuthUserProvider::class);
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot!

Comment: But did it answer your question?

Comment: Well, sort of, it made me dig a little deeper and learn more as i figure it out, so thanks.