# How to create a custom provider based on UserProvider and register it properly

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, passwords

How to create a custom provider based on UserProvider and register it properly. I want to create a custom way of comparing passwords. I have the following:

StaffServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider as UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;


class StaffServiceProvider extends UserProvider {

    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];
        if (sha1($plain) == $user->getAuthPassword()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

config/app.php

```
    'providers' => [
      ...

//      CUSTOM
        App\Providers\StaffServiceProvider::class,
```

and I'm getting this error. How do I fix it

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\zeemed\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php on line 208
```

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728219/laravel-overriding-eloquentuserprovider-to-change-password-field-name-in-validat

Comment: Thanks but they're not proposing any solution.